# Signing the assembly in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, security, encryption

I have an assembly say "BankingSecurity.dll" in visual studio 2008.

I need to sign/encrypt this assembly so that it cannot be decrypted by hackers.

Please note that I need not sign my entire application, I need to sign/encrypt only this dll out of some 30 dlls.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can't you just open the DLL in question in Visual Studio and sign it? I realise this is quite an old post.

Answer (score 2):

If it can be decrypted by legitimate users, it can also be decrypted by hackers. Application have no way to know who user is.